# Show activity indicator with lazy loading using AsyncImageView classes

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am using AsyncImageView classes to apply lazy loading on UITableView. And want to apply activity indicator on image view until the image is loaded on cell. Below is my code i am trying.

```
//  AsyncIamgeView.m

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {

//[connection release];
UIActivityIndicatorView     *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(15, 15);

connection=nil;

if ([[self subviews] count]>0) {
    [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}

UIImage *imgData = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
 [imageView addSubview:indicator];
[indicator startAnimating];

    if(imgData == nil)
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImagenew.png"]];
    //[indicator stopAnimating];
}
else{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgData];
   // [indicator stopAnimating];
}
//imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth || UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight );
//[imageView sizeToFit];
[self addSubview:imageView];

imageView.frame = self.bounds;
//imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 85, 94);
[imageView setNeedsLayout];
[self setNeedsLayout];
//[data release];
data=nil;
}

 //   cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

 asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 3, 85, 54)];
[asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImageView];
```

This code shows activity indicator but when image is loaded after that not before loading images. Please guide for above.

Comment: you are just stopping the activity indicator where are you removing it from view?

Comment: [imageView addSubview:indicator]; put this before getting data

Comment: @Rajneesh071 updated the code please check.

Comment: @iPhone6 hello dear u are using asynimage view classs na in that by default u will get the loader in the cell it self

Comment: AsyncIamgeView is it your own class or you downloaded it?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I downloaded it.

Comment: then what the need to do with connectionDidFinishLoading? just do this imageView.image.imageUrl=@"yourImage url" this will automaticly  add indicator

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I downloaded only AsyncIamgeView.h and .m files these does not have the method of indicator in it.

Comment: check my answer.. you don't need to apply indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are adding activity indicator when your image is downloaded.

Here is the simple idea, hope you can implement this in your code

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   // This method is called when your connection receives a response
   // add your activity indication here and start animating
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  // This method is called when your image is downloaded.
  // remove your activity indicator or stop animating here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create AsyncImageView object instead of UIImageView, then it will automatically add indicator to your view

```
AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 3, 85, 54)];
[cell addSubview:imageView];


//cancel loading previous image for cell
    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:imageView];

    //load the image
    imageView.imageURL = [imageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/blob/master/Examples/Effects%20Example/AsyncImageDemo/ImagesViewController.m) of this

Answer (score 0):

I think u are using asynimageview classs, In that by default you will get the loader in the cell itself .

Answer (score 0):

Hope u downloaded `AsyncImageView` from https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView. By default, it has the feature to show activity indicator. You just dont need to add or remove any code by yourself to get this feature works. Just call `loadImageWithURL`.

Answer (score 0):

AysncImageView already has a loader.

You won't see it if your background is black since it loads the default activity indicator.

So, just set the *activityIndicatorStyle* property for your AsyncImageView object based on your background.

In my case, my background was black, so I used the following code :

```
asyncImgView.activityIndicatorStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
```